# Can an Asus P7P55 LX motherboard support SSD's?

Tags: ssd, motherboard

After installing a new SSD in my PC, it got wrecked. 
I contacted ASUS and they told me my motherboard could not support so many SSD's. They told me maybe it could support two SSD's, but no way it could support three. (I currently have two and my computer is not working) So i guessed maybe I could remove one SSD and then It would work properlly. Another person in ASUS told me later that my board could not support any SSD'S. So I don't know ho told me the right thing: the guy who told me it could maybe support two but now way three, or the other guy who told me it could not support any SSD's.

As you can guess, I can't remove my operative system's SSD, because that would make my PC really slow, and I need speed for video editing and visual effects. Later on I found a blog where someone said the motherboard could support SSD's. What should I do? Just stay with one SSD and quit the other one, or should I quit both and take Windows to my HHD (which would be terrible)? Or does it depend on the power source? And if it can indeed support SSD's, how many can it support?
Thanks!

Comment: Do some research before posting questions.  In this case, you could certainly have simply searched for the mobo specs. https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55M/specifications/

Comment: BTW, why would you even think to put SSDs on such an ancient (2010!) motherboard?  I mean, this is so old that it still supports IDE/ATA drives!

Comment: @Debra you are completely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of posting the results here of the research we did together elsewhere so it can be useful to other people in the future.

The problem is the speed of the Marvell 9123 controller on the motherboard. This motherboard is a nearly 10 year old consumer grade design, and was never intended to handle the throughput of today's commodity SSD's.

See http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/284437-32-asus-p7p55d

A call to ASUS to determine whether or not you can get around this limit with an external adapter such as the Hyper M.2 X16 Card would be in order.  However, your most economical solution may be upgrade to a more current generation motherboard.